# Rows without repetitions - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, repeat, matrix-indexing

I have a `matrix` (4096x4) containing all possible combinations of four values taken from a pool of 8 numbers.

```
...
3    63    39     3
3    63    39    19
3    63    39    23
3    63    39    39
...
```

I am only interested in the rows of the matrix that contain four unique values. In the above section, for example, the first and last row should be removed, giving us -

```
...
3    63    39    19
3    63    39    23
...
```

---

My current solution feels inelegant-- basically, I iterate across every row and add it to a `result` matrix if it contains four unique values:

```
result = [];
for row = 1:size(matrix,1)
    if length(unique(matrix(row,:)))==4
        result =  cat(1,result,matrix(row,:));
    end
end
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: `nchoosek` would be my recommended approach too. @rwong: You can pass a vector instead of a number as first input, and then you get the combinations, not just the count. For example, `nchoosek(1:8,4)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Approach #1

**[`diff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html)**  and **[`sort`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)** based approach that must be pretty efficient -

```
sortedmatrix = sort(matrix,2)
result = matrix(all(diff(sortedmatrix,[],2)~=0,2),:)
```

**Breaking it down to few steps for explanation**

1. Sort along the columns, so that the duplicate values in each row end up next to each other. We used `sort` for this task.
2. Find the difference between consecutive elements, which will catch those duplicate after sorting. `diff` was the tool for this purpose.
3. For any row with `at least one zero` indicates rows with duplicate rows. To put it other way, any row with `no zero` would indicate rows with no duplicate rows, which we are looking to have in the output. `all` got us the job done here to get a logical array of such matches.
4. Finally, we have used `matrix indexing` to select those rows from `matrix` to get the expected output.

---

### Approach #2

This could be an *experimental* **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** based approach as it won't be memory-efficient -

```
matches = bsxfun(@eq,matrix,permute(matrix,[1 3 2]))
result = matrix(all(all(sum(matches,2)==1,2),3),:)
```

**Breaking it down to few steps for explanation**

1. Find a logical array of matches for every element against all others in the same row with `bsxfun`.
2. Look for "non-duplicity" by summing those matches along `dim-2` of matches and then finding `all ones` elements along `dim-2` and `dim-3` getting us the same indexing array as had with our previous `diff + sort` based approach.
3. Use the binary indexing array to select the appropriate rows from `matrix` for the final output.

---

### Approach #3

Taking help from MATLAB File-exchange's post [`combinator`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations)
and assuming you have the pool of `8` values in an array named `pool8`, you can directly get `result` like so -

```
result = pool8(combinator(8,4,'p'))
```

`combinator(8,4,'p')` basically gets us the indices for `8` elements taken `4` at once and without repetitions. We use these indices to index into the `pool` and get the expected output.

Comment: Approach 1 was exactly the sort of thing i was hoping to find out about!

Answer (score 1):

For a pool of a finite number this will work.  Create is unique array, go through each number in pool, count the number of times it comes up in the row, and only keep `IsUnique` to 1 if there are either one or zero numbers found.  Next, find positions where the `IsUnique` is still 1, extract those rows and we finish.

```
matrix = [3,63,39,3;3,63,39,19;3,63,39,23;3,63,39,39;3,63,39,39;3,63,39,39];
    IsUnique = ones(size(matrix,1),1);
    pool = [3,63,39,19,23,6,7,8];
    for NumberInPool = 1:8    
        Temp = sum((matrix == pool(NumberInPool))')';
        IsUnique = IsUnique .* (Temp<2);
    end
    UniquePositions = find(IsUnique==1);
    result = matrix(UniquePositions,:)
```